# Keep duplicates ID only if there is no new information

Tags: sas

I want to keep all duplicate IDs except if there is no new information due to missing values. For example,

```
data test;
input id var1 var2 var3
    datalines;
    1 2 3 4
    1 4 . 4
    1 6 5 4
    1 . 3 .
    1 2 4 4
    1 6 . 4
    1 . 8 4
    ;
run;
```

I want the result to be

```
1 2 3 4
1 4 . 4
1 6 5 4
1 2 4 4
1 . 8 4
```

Row 4 is removed because row 1 has the same id, var2 and var3. Row 6 is removed because row 3 has the same id, var1, var3. I also want a robust solution as I want the solution to work for any number of variables in the dataset (id would always be the unique key).

Any thoughts? I was thinking sort nodupkey but it doesn't work if there are more than one missing value in a row.

Comment: you said Row 4 is removed because row 1 has the same id, var2 and var3(but var3 is missing)

Comment: So you only want to keep rows that contain at least one previously unseen, non-missing value for at least one variable (per id) ? 

If there was an extra row with `var1 = 2, var2 = 5, var3 = 4`, would you keep that (as it's a new combination of values) or would you drop it because each individual value has been seen before?

Comment: If they are different because one of them is missing, I consider it the same.
I would keep the new combination of values.

Comment: If you have two duplicates, do you have any preference for which one you want to keep? e.g. the first one? Or does the order not matter?

Comment: order doesn't matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract rows, that has one ore more missing.
On the second step you must generate RegExp, that help you identify similar rows.

Code may be improve by your suggesion.

```
data test;
input id var1 var2 var3;
    datalines;
    1 2 3 4
    1 4 . 4
    1 6 5 4
    1 . 3 .
    1 2 4 4
    1 6 . 4
    1 . 8 4
    ;
run;

data test2 missing;
/*incrase this strings if you have big values*/
length res $ 200 addedEl $ 10;
    set test;
    array num _NUMERIC_;

    /*add flag  to determine is there missin in row*/
    flag=0;
    do i=1 to dim(num);
        addedEl=compress(put(num(i),8.));
        if num(i)=. then
            do;
                flag=1;
                /*template for number. If you have comma separated vars then replace on \d+\.\d*        */
                addedEl="\d+";
            end;
        /*add delimeter to row parse, if you have more than one digits in vars =)*/
        res=catx("_",res,addedEl);
    end;


    if flag=0 then  output test2;
    else    do;
        res=catt("/",res,"/");
        output missing;
    end;


    drop i flag addedEl;
run;

/*determine rows that dublicates*/
proc sql noprint;
create table matched as
  select  B.* 
          ,prxparse(B.res) as prxm 
          ,A.*
  from  test2 as A
        ,missing as B
  where prxmatch(calculated prxm,A.res)
  order by B.res;
quit;
run;

/*pre-merge sort*/
proc sort data=missing;
    by res;
run;

/*delete rows that are in second dataset*/
data miss_correctred;
    merge missing(in=mss)
        matched(in=mtch)
    ;
    by res;

    if mss=1 and mtch=0;
run;

data test_res(drop=prxm res);
    set test2 miss_correctred;
run;
```

result:

```
+----+------+------+------+
| id | var1 | var2 | var3 |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 |    2 |    3 |    4 |
|  1 |    6 |    5 |    4 |
|  1 |    2 |    4 |    4 |
|  1 |    4 |    . |    4 |
|  1 |    . |    8 |    4 |
+----+------+------+------+
```

Comment: This relies on a cartesian join within each id matching lots of strings against lots of different regular expressions. Full marks for ingenuity, but I'm not sure how well the performance is going to scale for large numbers of rows per id.

Comment: @user667489, I agree about performance. But may be this answer get push to another suggesions. The task is interesting

Comment: On the other hand, given the nature of the task it's hard to see how one could make it perform any better. There's probably a hash / macro approach but it starts getting messy when you look for previously unseen combinations of *any* 2+ variables.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the outline of a single data step hash + double DOW approach:

- For each id:

  - Create a hash object + iterator with all variables as keys
  - Attempt to load all rows for that id into the hash. This is equivalent to an initial pass with proc sort nodupkey.
  - Make a second pass through all the rows for the same id (double DOW), skipping any that contain only non-missing values.

    - Count each row as a duplicate by default
    - For each pair of variables with at least one non-missing value in the current row:

      - Check if that pair of values is present in any previous item in the hash.
    - Mark the row as non-duplicate if we find at least one pair of values that don't match anywhere in the hash. Treat missing values in the current row as matches. As soon as a row is marked as non-duplicate, we can move on to the next row.

I think this is worst-case O(n^4), but if there is a high proportion of duplicates then it should do better.

## Update:

Here's a sample implementation - this was indeed quite messy:

```
proc sql noprint;
  select 
    quote(trim(name)), 
    name,
    count(name) 
  into 
    :varlist separated by ',', 
    :arraylist separated by ' ',
    :varcount
  from dictionary.columns 
  where 
    libname = 'WORK' 
    and memname = 'TEST' 
    and type = 'num'
    and name ne 'id'
  ; 
quit;

data want;
  /*Set up arrays*/
  if 0 then set test;
  array vars[*] &arraylist;
  array temp[&varcount] _temporary_;
  length sub_id 8;
  keep id &arraylist;

  /*Set up hash + iterator*/
  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    declare hash h(ordered:'a');
    rc = h.definekey('sub_id', &varlist);
    rc = h.definedata('sub_id', &varlist);
    rc = h.definedone();
    declare hiter hi('h');
  end;

  /*DOW #1 - load hash and output definite non-duplicates*/
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until(last.id);
    set test;
    by id;
    /*We need a way to keep track of rows within each id so that we don't count rows as duplicates when they match themselves in DOW #2*/
    sub_id = _n_;
    rc = h.add();
    if rc = 0 and nmiss(of vars[*]) = 0 then output;
  end;

  /*DOW #2 - check for any previously unseen pairs of values*/
  do _n_ = 1 to _n_;
    set test;
    /*Make a copy of the current row to retrieve after looping through the hash iterator*/
    do i = 1 to dim(vars);
      temp[i] = vars[i];
    end;
    if nmiss(of vars[*]) > 0 then do;
      dup_flag = 1;
      /*Work through successive pairs of values*/
      do i = 1 to dim(vars) while(dup_flag = 1);
        do j = 1 to i - 1 while(dup_flag = 1);
          __v_i = temp[i];
          __v_j = temp[j];
          match_flag = 0;
          /*For each pair, loop through the iterator until we find a 'match'*/
          rc = hi.first();
          do while(rc = 0 and match_flag = 0 and sub_id < _n_);            
            if    (missing(__v_i) or __v_i = vars[i])
              and (missing(__v_j) or __v_j = vars[j])
              then match_flag = 1;
            rc = hi.next();
          end;
          /*If we didn't find a match, we have a new combination and the row is not a duplicate*/
          if match_flag = 0 then dup_flag = 0;
        end;
      end;
      if dup_flag = 0 then do;
        do i = 1 to dim(vars);
          vars[i] = temp[i];
        end;
        output;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  rc = h.clear();
run;
```